# Internet Explorer 11 not saving cookies in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a huge problem, at work I am working with an asp.net application. On chrome and other browsers cookies are saved properly and allow a pleasant user experience, but on IE there are times when the browser doesn't save the cookies, it is not always, but everytime it fails it requests the user for a login.

It is not an underscore or character's problem since the error happens in localhost too, the code that deals with the cookies currently is this one:

```
public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
        if (createPersistentCookie)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

I am at wit's end and I need to solve this today.

Is there anything else that could be added to make sure that IE always accepts a cookie? When deleting the cache or resetting IE the cookies stop being saved. I need help.

Thanks,

Comment: Just one user, or all of them?

Comment: @stuartd all of them